# Downloading large files in Angular with Header Authentication

Tags: angular, download, stream, header

We have an Angular 6 application that used to download large generated files from the backend using streaming meaning neither the backend nor the client did ever load the whole file into memory because those files could be hundreds or thousands of MB. We used the following response headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=<generated filename>
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
```

We used `window.open(exportLink, '_blank')` which worked fine when using Cookie-based authentication. We've now *changed to header-based tokens*. Now, the backend returns a 403 because of the missing header.

I understand, that using any of the methods like `windows.open` and `windows.location` do not support passing headers.

The only option then would be to use the client API (e.g. Angular HTTP client + FileSaver). This however *does not work for large files* since it will reach the browsers memory limit.

We tried [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) together with the Angular HTTP client which seems not to work properly. We also tried to use the browser Fetch API together with stream saver.

Using the latter similar to the example provided in the StreamSaver repo seems to work (meaning console output suggests that file saving was successful) but we don't see any file download indication in the browser.

Has anyone implemented large file stream downloads with header-based token authentication and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can try is single-use-token:

- Add endpoint under usual authentication that will return link in format ?token=token
- Add download endpoint under single-token authentication to download files (and remove token)

when u need to download file - u first get url using 1st endpoint, then download it any way u prefer

Comment: Theoretically, that would be an option, but it would require state in the backend. We would either keep the single token in memory which would loose one of the 12 factors or we would need to store it in data base which is a larger effort implement.

Comment: I accepted this answer because we couldn't find any client-only solution and this seems to mee the most elegant and secure solution because we would then generate one-time tokens. But as I said, this requires some effort to implement in a distributed system. We actually worked-around it, by changing the proxy to accept an `access_token` url param and rewruting it to the appropriate header field.